# How to use a Postman Mock Server

Tags: api, postman

I have followed [the guide here to create a postman mock](https://www.getpostman.com/docs/postman/mock_servers) for a postman collection. The mock seem to be successfully created, but I have no idea how to use the mock service.

I've been given a url for the mock, but how do I specify one of my requests? If I issue a GET request to  `https://{{mockid}}.mock.pstmn.io` I get the following response:

```
{
    "error": {
        "name": "mockRequestNotFoundError",
        "message": "We were unable to find any matching requests for the mock path (i.e. undefined) in your collection."
    }
}
```

According to the [same guide mentioned above](https://www.getpostman.com/docs/postman/mock_servers) the following url to "run the mock" `https://{{mockId}}.mock.pstmn.io/{{mockPath}}` but what exactly is `mockPath`?

Within my collection I have plenty of folders, and inside one of these folders I have a request with an example response. How do I access this example response through the mock? Thanks for all help in advance!

[Here's the Postman Pro API](https://docs.api.getpostman.com/#1876fce7-f88a-4f68-08ac-df4275b6f0b2), which doesnt mention a lot more than just creating reading mocks.

Comment: I'm wondering that too, how does Postman Mock server actually map request URLs to `mockPath`? Does it assume all request URLs have the same domain and simply map the path to `mockPath`? What if I have different domains in a given collection, what `mockPath` would I use then?

Comment: @PetrusK. - Currently mock does not distinguish between domains within a collection. It will deterministically return the first one in order if it hits the same http verb, path and `x-mock-response-code` for multiple examples.

Comment: @PratikMandrekar Does that mean it will also deterministically return the first one in order if multiple folders contain the exact same request (I mean request URL)? We for example use the same request url (but with different body data) throughout folders.

Comment: @JimAho - Yes, the response will be deterministic. If it returns one response for a URL it will return the same one the next time as well for the same collection.

Answer (score 10):

I had the same issue seeing an irrelevant error but finally I found the solution. Unfortunately I cannot find a reference in Postman website. But here is my solution:

When you create a Mock server you define your first request (like GET api/v1/about). So the Mock server will be created but even when you obtain your API key and put it in the header of request (as x-api-key) it still returns an error. It doesn't make sense but it turned out that defining the request is not enough. For me it only started returning a response when I added an Example for the request.

So I suggest for each request that you create, also create at least one example. The request you send will be matched with the examples you have created and the matched response will be returned. **You can define *body*, *headers* and the HTTP *status* code of the example response.**.

I have no Pro Postman subscription and it worked for me using my free subscription.

**Menu for adding an example or selecting one of them for editing:**
[image]

**UI for defining the example (See body, headers and status) :**
[image]

**How to go back to the request page:**
[image]

**Here is the correct reply I get based on my example:**
[image]

Comment: Does anyone know how to specify which example should be run if an api call is made by app code? For now looks like the first one that was created will run, but is there any way to change it?

Comment: having trouble understanding how to add headers to a canned response

Answer (score 5):

If you request in the example is a `GET` on `api.domain.com/api/foo` then the mockPath is `/api/foo` and your mock endpoint is a `GET` call to `https://{{mockid}}.mock.pstmn.io/api/foo`.

The [HTTP request methods](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Methods) and the the pathname as shown in the image below constitute a mock.

[image: breaking down a url]

For ease of use the mock server is designed to be used on top of collections. The request in the [examples](http://blog.getpostman.com/2017/05/17/mock-responses-in-postman-by-using-examples/) is used as is along with response attached to it. The name of the folder or collection is not a part of the pathname and is not factored in anywhere when using a mock. Mocking a collection means mocking all the examples in within your collection. An example is a tuple of request and response.

An optional response status code if specified lets you fetch the appropriate response for the same path. This can be specified with the `x-mock-response-code` header. So passing `x-mock-response-code` as `404` will return the example that matches the pathname and has a response with status code of `404`.

Currently if there are examples with the same path but different domains, and mock is unable to distinguish between them it will deterministically return the first one.

Comment: I have a couple of folders inside my collection, and each folder can very well contain the same request as other folders. So assume I have two requests for `api.domain.com/api/foo` how does the mock know which request to pick?

Comment: @JimAho What differentiates the requests between two folders? How do similar requests in two different folders behave differently?

Comment: Nothing differentiates them, the reason why I have them duplicated is because when I use the postman runner feature and target a collection and folder, I want it to contain all neccessary requests. They do not behave differently, but only one of them might have example requests saved (which I understand is what the Mock Server uses).

Comment: Yeah you shouldn't have a problem making the mock behave as expected with this arrangement.

Answer (score 0):

Also if you have several examples for the same query :

Mock request accept another optional header, **x-mock-response-code**, which specifies which integer response code your returned response should match. For example, 500 will return only a 500 response. If this header is not provided, the closest match of any response code will be returned.

Optional headers like x-mock-response-name or x-mock-response-id allow you to further specify the exact response you want by the name or by the uid of the saved example respectively.

[Here's](https://learning.postman.com/docs/designing-and-developing-your-api/mocking-data/mock-with-api/#run-the-mock-service) the documentation for more details.

Answer (score 0):

`{{mockPath}}` is simply the path for your request. You should start by adding an example for any of your requests.

Example:

Request: `https://www.google.com/path/to/my/api`

After adding your mock server, you can access your examples at:

```
https://{{mockId}}.mock.pstmn.io/path/to/my/api
```